# Is there any way to track and kill a Postgres query in Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, postgresql, zend-db

I am working on a project using Zend Framework, PHP 5.3, and PostGres.  I have built a javascript front end that relies heavily on AJAX requests.

For instance, any time a user tries to add a new field( which is very common), a request is sent that triggers a long running query (5-10 seconds).  If the user adds 5 in a row, thats potentially 60 seconds to get the correct query value.

I would like to kill the current  AJAX request and DB Query every time a successive request is received. 
Is there a means in Zend to track that query and kill it if a successive ajax request is received?

To give you an idea of what I'm currently working with -

```
 $db = Zend_Registry::get('database');
$select = 'SELECT get_Query(' . $this->client_id  ')';
$data = $db->query($select)->fetchAll();

return $data;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/database/how-to-kill-terminate-postgresql-hang-query/), you can search the output of `ps -ef` for postgres queries with a status of "idle in transaction" and terminate those queries using `kill`

This will require the use of `exec()` or a similar function to execute system commands.